# Remove Maui TableView Separator

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Is it possible to remove the separator from the .net Maui TableView?
The Documentation is suspiciously silent about that topic.
If it is impossible to remove, is it possible to change its color?

For example:  `<Setter Property="SeparatorColor" Value="Transparent" />`

I am looking for something like the SeparatorVisibility or the SeparatorColor of the ListView.

Comment: Which platform do you want to remove the separator of TableView in Maui? As the `Separator` of `TableView` only works in `Android` and it fails to show the `Separator` in `Windows`. For now, I think we need eliminate the differences between platforms to remove it. This could be a potential issue, you may need to open a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github.